# #N/A using vlookup in excel

Tags: excel

I'm not sure why I get `#N/A` here. I a trying to get the retrieve the number of pages for paper 360.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F3,B:B,0)),"Value does not excist")
```

Comment: Using index and match avoids having to re-order data, so a neat solution especially if other things rely on the existing data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry I solved it. I realized vlookup looks in the first column of my table, so I swapped the order of columns in my table and that fixed it.

Comment: it s not necessary to switch columns, you could use index  & match

Comment: That just highlights the major limitation of vlookup and why index with match is **so** much more flexible, even to having the data in different locations or sheets...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to see if your A column has the "360" value? Maybe if you try to change the value of 360 in F2 (C/L) to 5, the value of 10 will be returned.